# How to avoid multiple ssh to contact remote?

Tags: python, bash, shell, ssh, scp

```
ssh researcher@192.168.1.1 'ls somefile' > folders.txt
echo "Trying to connect and show files from Remote"
scp researcher@192.168.1.1:somefile somefile
```

From the code we can see that iam using a ssh session to first look for all files and again iam establishing another ssh session to download files.Ignore any content or syntax errors(I have replaced some confidential info).

So everytime i try to connect to remote it asks me password,and this process alone takes 3-4 seconds and my script has 4 ssh calls and this is taking a lot of time.So instead of connecting for 4 times , is there a way so i can connect only once and maintain session and do remaining calls.

Help me with suggestions to do this.

Comment: `man ssh-agent`

Comment: Why don't you just run scp? If the file doesn't exist it won't copy back anything.  This is the best single pass. If you want to avoid password less setup ssh keys.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, there is a legitimate need to open multiple connections, either sequentially or in parallel. For those cases, you can run one `ssh` in master mode, which establishes the connection, and run the others in control mode, which "piggyback" on the first connection, avoiding the need to authenticate again.

```
# * -M puts the connection in master mode
#
# * ControlPersist keeps the connection alive after the current client
#   exits, for use by other clients
#
# * ControlPath specifies the socket to use. %C expands to a combination
#   of the local and remote host names, the user id, and the port.
#   It should be in a directory writeable only by you, but for this
#   example we just put it in the current directory. The same socket
#   is used by each client wishing to piggyback on the open connection.

ssh -M -o ControlPersist=yes -o ControlPath=%C researcher@192.168.1.1  ls somefile > folders.txt

scp -o ControlPath=%C researcher@192.168.1.1:somefile somefile
# -O simply sends a command to the master connection, in this case
# closing it.
ssh -o ControlPath=%C -O exit researcher@192.168.1.1  # end the session
```

You can automate a lot of this by adding the appropriate options to your `.ssh/config` file instead of repeating them on the command line. See the various `Control*` options in `man ssh_config` for more detail.